# React-final-form - input losing focus after every keystroke

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

```js
import React from "react";
import { Field, Form } from "react-final-form";

export function LogInDialog(props: { open: boolean; onClose: () => void }) {
  const onSubmit = vals => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(vals));
  };
    console.log("logindialog");
  return (
    <Form
      key="unique_key_0"
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} key="unique_key_1" id="unique_id_1">
          <Field
            key="unique_key_2"
            id="unique_id_2"
            name="email"
            component={({ input: { onChange, value }, label }) => (
              <input
                key="unique_key_3"
                id="unique_id_3"
                type="text"
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            )}
          ></Field>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

The input is losing its focus after every keystroke. In devtools, I can see the HTML `form` is created anew every time (it flashes pink). The React component itself however goes through rendering only once.

There are similar questions, however all of them suggest using unique keys. Such a solution doesn't seem to be working here.

**Why is the input losing its focus over and over again? How do I fix it?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-torvalds-91zln

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an inline lambda is used for the component, its identity changes every render.

While according to many other questions an unique key should be enough, moving the `component` function outside the master component fixes it altogether.